# Portable python package to other platform?

Tags: python, package, portability

Suppose I have a Windows machine A, the python package x is installed and used in script.py as:

```
#this is in script.py
import x 
x.useit()
```

Then I can execute script.py in machine A like:

```
python script.py
```

Now if I copy script.py to a Mac machine B, is there a way to run script.py without install the package x there?

Comment: Yes ... it's known as packaging

Comment: Hi Joran, do you have more info? Thanks

Comment: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Hi jgmao do you have more info? Thanks .... Otherwise google is your friend

Comment: OK, I got it. But what if I don't want to use pip, but simply want to make a package and copy it directly to the machine B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only way i think it works is using some modules like py2exe, py2app ...
when u importing modules u are calling some functions and classes... so u need them for running them  in program. 
maybe there is hard way  that u can copy the  module in your program(the lines u need at least..!) but i think its little dumb! and i didn't try before!

so hopefully py2app is ready to use and i think py2app will work for sure !